# transpiling es6 with gulp-babel using babel-preset-env is too slow

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I'm working on a better workflow for my company's frontend team. We mostly work with "normal" website projects, so no SPAs, mostly jquery or a little VueJS here and there, but no React or whatever is cool these days. Right now we use a pretty solid gulp workflow, that I like. There's only one issue: I'd love to write es6 and use babel-preset-env for the transpiling/autoprefixing etc..

Now, I got it to work but it is kinda slow, here's a reduced test case:

### input file

some concat'd file from an old project I ran through [lebab.io](https://lebab.io/try-it) to es6ify it, roughly 237k in size. My reasoning is, that that is a representative size (as in LOC) of a codebase that might occur in a project we do.

`-rw-r--r--    1 foo  staff   237K 27 Okt 19:53 foobar.js`

### gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task("js", () => {
    return gulp
        .src("./foobar.js")
        .pipe(
            babel({
                minified: true,
                comments: false,
                presets: [
                    [
                        "env",
                        {
                            targets: {
                                browsers: ["last 2 versions"]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./bundle.js"));
});
```

### gulp output without preset

`[19:54:30] Finished 'js' after 1.42 s`

I ran this a couple of times with similar timing results, ~1.4s;

### gulp output with preset "env"

`[19:55:37] Finished 'js' after 2.46 s`

… which is a little too long for using it in our watch task.

**Now my question:** is that what I should have to expect from using preset-env or is there something wrong with my setup? I would like to convinve my colleagues to switch over to es6 syntax but if the build process wait is too annoying (> 2s), I don't see it happening.

Is there a better way to transpile for older browsers using gulp? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You should ask such questions in Babel's Github repo and not here, this is not the ideal place. Those guys made the changes so they should provide the answers for your slowdown.